# asp.net forms authentication occasionally redirects to default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Am using forms authentication along with the asp.net login controls in my website. Based on the roles i have to redirect my users to two different pages.

The code works but occasionally it takes me to either default.aspx which is not present and sometimes it simple refreshes my current login page. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code behind

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] rolenames = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
    if (rolenames.Length > 0)
    {            
        if (rolenames[0] == "Administrators")
            Response.Redirect("~/Administrators/Home.aspx");
        else if (rolenames[0] == "Employees")
            Response.Redirect("~/Employees/Home.aspx");
    }
}
```

and following markup from web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
         slidingExpiration="true" 
         cookieless="AutoDetect"
         ></forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: What if user has no roles? It will redirect to a default page then, I guess. You lack the clause to handle this branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the default condition, what if none of the above IF condition holds true ?
That case it will just refresh the current page after post back.

You forgot to mention code behind **Login1_LoggedIn** is on which page ?

Answer (score 0):

And What happens if The rolenames[0]  is not and "Administrators" or "Employees"?
Set a default condition and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi osahon! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just for future reference, an answer like this that is rather cursory and doesn't go into a whole lot of detail is best left as a comment on the question, not a full answer. See Wiktor's comment to see what I'm talking about. Thanks!